# ksoap cannot serialize date although using marshal

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

Im a newbie in android and I have problem when i send a date from my Android (Java) app to the .NET web service (JSON). I see some solution in [here](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html).But it not working for me. 
[there is my webservices](http://vuongphgc60287.somee.com/mywebservices.asmx)

My json data here:

```
[{"ID_Ticket":"T01","Company":"Dien Linh","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"10:00","Price":1000000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T02","Company":"Anh Tuyen","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"10:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T03","Company":"Son Lam","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"12:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T04","Company":"Phuong Trang","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"14:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T05","Company":"Mai Linh","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"16:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T06","Company":"To Chau","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"18:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T07","Company":"Le Chau","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"20:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T08","Company":"Phuong Nha","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"20:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T09","Company":"Kim Huong","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"22:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T12","Company":"Tuan Hung","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"21:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"},{"ID_Ticket":"T13","Company":"Hoang Anh","Departure":"Ho Chi Minh","Arrival":"Ha Noi","Vehicles_type":"vehicles sleepers","Services":"Wifi, cold tower, Water, Foods","Date":"08/13/2015","Time":"10:00","Price":1200000,"Ticket_Status":"Still"}]
```

Here is My MarshaDate class:

```
@Override
public Object readInstance(XmlPullParser xmlPullParser, String namespace, String name, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    return IsoDate.stringToDate(xmlPullParser.nextText(),IsoDate.DATE_TIME);
}

@Override
public void writeInstance(XmlSerializer xmlSerializer, Object o) throws IOException {
    xmlSerializer.text(IsoDate.dateToString((Date) o, IsoDate.DATE_TIME));
}

@Override
public void register(SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope) {
    soapSerializationEnvelope.addMapping(soapSerializationEnvelope.xsd, "DateTime", Date.class, this);
}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```
 private EditText departure;
private EditText arrival;
private EditText date;
private ListView listView;
private TextView tvtest;
private ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList;
private ArrayList<TicketInforModel> ticketInforModelArrayList;
private TicketInforModel ticketInforModel;
private ArrayAdapter<TicketInforModel> arrAdapterTicket;
private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.searchticket_main);

    departure = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_departure);
    arrival = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_arrival);
    date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_date);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_ticket);
    tvtest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_test);

    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
    setDateTimeField();

    Button btn_searching = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_searching);
    btn_searching.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSonAsyncTask task=new JSonAsyncTask();
            task.execute();
        }
    });


}

private void showMessages(String messages) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Notification").setMessage(messages).setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    }).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == date) {
        fromDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
}

public class JSonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<JSONObject>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<JSONObject> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList<JSONObject> listJSon=new ArrayList<>();
        String TAG_SOAPACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/searchingTickets";
        String TAG_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
        String TAG_METHODNAME = "searchingTickets";
        String TAG_URL = "http://vuongphgc60287.somee.com/mywebservices.asmx";
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        MarshaDate marshaDate = new MarshaDate();
        marshaDate.register(envelope);

        SoapObject request=new SoapObject(TAG_NAMESPACE, TAG_METHODNAME);
        request.addProperty("date", date.getText());
        request.addProperty("departure",departure.getText());
        request.addProperty("arrival",arrival.getText());
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transport=new HttpTransportSE(TAG_URL);
        try{
            transport.call(TAG_SOAPACTION1,envelope);
            SoapPrimitive data= (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            String jsonText=data.toString();
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonText);
            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                listJSon.add(jsonObject);
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.d("JSON",e.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
            soapFault.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listJSon;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<JSONObject> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        arrayList.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(result);

    }
}

public void arrAdapter() throws JSONException {
    String TAG_IDTICKET = "ID_Ticket";
    String TAG_Company = "Company";
    String TAG_Departure = "Departure";
    String TAG_Arrival = "Arrival";
    String TAG_VEHICLESTYPE = "Vehicles_type";
    String TAG_SERVICES = "Services";
    String TAG_Date = "Date";
    String TAG_Time = "Time";
    String TAG_Price = "Price";
    String TAG_TicketStatus = "Ticket_Status";
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        ticketInforModel = new TicketInforModel();
        ticketInforModel.set_IdTicket(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_IDTICKET).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_company(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Company).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_departure(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Departure).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_arrival(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Arrival).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_vehicletype(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_VEHICLESTYPE).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_services(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_SERVICES).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_date(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Date).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_time(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Time).toString());
        ticketInforModel.set_price(Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_Price).toString()));
        ticketInforModel.set_ticket_Status(arrayList.get(i).getString(TAG_TicketStatus).toString());
        ticketInforModelArrayList.add(ticketInforModel);
    }
}

public void loadDataToListView() throws JSONException {
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_ticket);
    arrAdapterTicket = new viewListTicket();
    listView.setAdapter(arrAdapterTicket);
}

class viewListTicket extends ArrayAdapter<TicketInforModel>{
    viewListTicket(){
        super(SearchTicketActivity.this,R.layout.ticket_design,ticketInforModelArrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.ticket_design, parent, false);
        }
        TicketInforModel currentTicket = ticketInforModelArrayList.get(position);
        TextView tv_time = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        tv_time.setText(currentTicket.get_time());

        TextView tv_company = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_company);
        tv_company.setText(currentTicket.get_company());

        TextView tv_phone = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_phone);
        tv_phone.setText("1111");

        TextView tv_price= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price);
        tv_price.setText(((Double.toString(currentTicket.get_price())) ));

        TextView tv_service= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_services);
        tv_service.setText(currentTicket.get_services());

        return itemView;
    }
}

private void setDateTimeField() {
    try {
        date.setOnClickListener(this);
        final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                ;
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth - 1);
                if (newDate.getTime().getTime() > (newCalendar.getTime().getTime())) {
                    final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchTicketActivity.this).setTitle("Notification").setMessage("Can not do that").show();

                    //this code below is coppied in https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/auto-close-dialog-after-a-specific-time/
                    final Timer t = new Timer();
                    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        public void run() {
                            builder.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
                            t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
                        }
                    }, 2000); // after 2 second (or 2000 miliseconds), the task will be active.
                    date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newCalendar.getTime()));

                } else {
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                }
            }
        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        showMessages("Something Wrong!");
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The problem appears when i try input date = "08/13/2015":

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 08/13/2015
```

Please give me some advices to resolve this problem. thanks you.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: sorry, this problem makes me mad. I just edit it and show my problem. Thanks for your comment.